# ¿Cómo puedo crear una clase a partir de un JSONObject con GSON (Uso Volley)?

Tags: android, json, api, gson, volley

tengo este método que crea un jsonobject a partir del jsonarray. Pero ahora quisiera que GSON convirtiese ese jsonobject en un objeto de una clase que yo tengo creada llamaba Amiibo. Gracias. Este es mi código:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsArray = response.getJSONArray("amiibo");
                    for(int i = 0;i < jsArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject object = jsArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                        list.add(gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(object), Amiibos.class));
                    }
                    miTextView.setText(list.get(5).toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Error Respuesta en JSON: " + error.getMessage());

                    }
                });
        requestQueue.add(jsObjectRequest);
```

Y aquí mi clase Amiibo:

```
public class Amiibos {
    String serie;
    String Personaje;
    String juegoSerie;
    String cabecera;
    int imagen;
    String nombre;
    String cola;
    String tipo;

    public Amiibos(String serie, String personaje, String juegoSerie, String cabecera, int imagen, String nombre, String cola, String tipo) {
        this.serie = serie;
        this.juegoSerie = juegoSerie;
        this.cabecera = cabecera;
        this.imagen = imagen;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cola = cola;
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }     
    }

    public String getSerie() {
        return serie;
    }

    public void setSerie(String serie) {
        this.serie = serie;
    }

    public String getPersonaje() {
        return Personaje;
    }

    public void setPersonaje(String personaje) {
        Personaje = personaje;
    }

    public String getJuegoSerie() {
        return juegoSerie;
    }

    public void setJuegoSerie(String juegoSerie) {
        this.juegoSerie = juegoSerie;
    }

    public String getCabecera() {
        return cabecera;
    }

    public void setCabecera(String cabecera) {
        this.cabecera = cabecera;
    }

    public int getImagen() {
        return imagen;
    }

    public void setImagen(int imagen) {
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getCola() {
        return cola;
    }

    public void setCola(String cola) {
        this.cola = cola;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }
```

Comment: No veo que utilices la clase `Gson` por ningún lado.

Comment: Ya lo he editado, dentro del for he añadido list.add(gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(object), Amiibos.class));
Pero cuando intento sacar el tamaño de la lista en el textview, no se cambia el textview. Gracias.

Comment: Tu clase Amiibos  no hace match con los elementos de la respuesta json, tienes que  mapear los valores de la respuesta mediante SerializedName, agregue respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente tienes que mapear los campos de tu clase `Amiibos` con los de la respuesta

```
{
  "amiibo": [
    {
      "amiiboSeries": "Super Smash Bros.", 
      "character": "Mario", 
      "gameSeries": "Super Mario", 
      "head": "00000000", 
      "image": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/N3evin/AmiiboAPI/master/images/icon_00000000-00000002.png", 
      "name": "Mario", 
....
```

usando la anotación  `SerializedName` , por ejemplo:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Amiibos {
    @SerializedName("amiiboSeries")
    String serie;
    @SerializedName("character")
    String Personaje;
    @SerializedName("name")
    String nombre;
    ...
    ...
```

Posteriormente crea el array a partir de la respuesta :

```
   Gson gson = new Gson(); //Instancia Gson.
   JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("amiibo");
   Amiibos[] arrJson = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), Amiibos[].class);
```

Con esto tendrás los datos dentro de un Objeto GSON, para validar puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
            for(Amiibos objJson : arrJson){
                if(objJson!=null) {
                    Log.i("Nombre", objJson.getNombre());
                    Log.i("Serie: ", objJson.getSerie());
                }
            }
```

---

No olvides agregar la dependencia de [**GSON**](https://github.com/google/gson) en tu archivo `build.gradle` para poder usar sus clases :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero me da un error que detiene la app, de NumberFormatException en arrJson

Comment: Comenta que cambios realizaste. Me parece que modificaste la clase Amiibos, es así?

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que estas Utilizando ArrayList.

Siendo Asi El Tamaño del Array lo podes obtener con :

```
list.size();
```

Obtener el valor de un campo de una posicion especifica por ejemplo el campo Personaje en la posicion 0,

```
list.get(0).getPersonaje();
```

Si Necesitas todos los campos lo podes recuperar con un for por ejemplo.

```
for (int i=0;i < list.size();i++){
        System.out.println("Personaje"+list.get(0).getPersonaje());

    }
```

y asi vas agregando todos los campos que desees ver,recorrer.!

> Recuerda para que Gson Funcione correctamente tus variables deben de llamarse exactamente iguales a los que estan el JSON.