# FromJson Gson error

Tags: java, android, gson

estoy tratando de descargar un JSON para luego, usando la libreria GSON, parsearlo usando el respectivo java class Respuesta.class: intento descargar el JSON del link:
String link = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/y76il"; estoy usando la siguiente sintaxis en el activity.class luego de establecer la conexión con loopj (ya verifique que se conecta y descarga el string de forma apropiada, también logro guardarlo en una variable "link")

```
Respuesta funt = gson.fromJson(json, Respuesta.class);
```

Pero parece que no lo hago de forma correcta ya que la aplicación siempre se detiene en esa linea de código, como debo proceder?

Adjunto la Respusta.class

```
public class Respuesta {

private int id;
private String name;
private UserBean user;
private ItemsBean items;

public int getId() {return id;}

public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}

public String getName() {return name;}

public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

public UserBean getUser() {return user;}

public void setUser(UserBean user) {this.user = user;}

public ItemsBean getItems() {return items;}

public void setItems(ItemsBean items) {this.items = items;}

public static class UserBean {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {return name;}

    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
}

public static class ItemsBean {

    private HashMap<String, CodigoBean> codigo;

    public HashMap<String, CodigoBean> getCodigo(){return codigo;}

    public void setCodigo(HashMap<String, CodigoBean> codigo) {this.codigo = codigo;}

    public static class CodigoBean {

        private int id;
        private int strong;
        private boolean active;
        private String sell;

        public int getId() {return id;}

        public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}

        public int getStrong() {return strong;}

        public void setStrong(int strong) {this.strong = strong;}

        public boolean isActive() {return active;}

        public void setActive(boolean active) {this.active = active;}

        public String getSell() {return sell;}

        public void setSell(String sell) {this.sell = sell;}
    }
}}
```

Adicional: estoy usando `HashMap<>` para mapear los códigos ya que puede ser un numero indeterminado de códigos ademas que no sabría como son, esta bien que utilice `HashMap<>` de esa manera?

Gracias de Antemano.

Comment: Se detiene o no compila? Por que esta expresión tiene que provocar un error de compilación: `String (link)`.

Comment: La app compila pero cuando descargo el JSON se detiene y el log especifica esa linea de código como el origen del error. realmente estoy guardando el sting de esta forma : Respuesta funt = gson.fromJson(json, Respuesta.class);

Comment: Pero pon la traza del error.

Comment: Creo que el problema es que la API devuelve un JSONArray (empieza por `[` y termina por `]`), no un JSONObject. Entonces tendrás que recuperar los datos así: **`Respuesta [] funt = gson.fromJson(json, Respuesta[].class);`**

Comment: re diseñe el JSON removiendo los corchetes [ ] y ya logre pasar el JSON a la clase java, gracias!.

Answer (score 0):

La estructura que tratas de parser es de un Json Array, ya que inicia con `"["`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además es importante mapear los campos de tu clase con los de la respuesta mediante la anotación  `SerializedName`

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Respuesta{

@SerializedName("id")
private int id;
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@SerializedName("user")   
...
...
```

de esta forma puedes obtener los valores en un array:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson(); //Instancia Gson.
 Respuesta[] arrJson = gson.fromJson(json.toString(), Respuesta[].class);
```

Aquí un ejemplo:

[¿Cómo puedo crear una clase a partir de un JSONObject con GSON (Uso Volley)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131875/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-crear-una-clase-a-partir-de-un-jsonobject-con-gson-uso-volley/131878#131878)